# Geoserver ImageMosaic BackgroundValue Ignored for non-RGB GeoTIFF

Tags: geoserver, wms, image-mosaic

I have a GeoServer (2.10.0) instance into which I have loaded some GeoTiff files, one per timestep, using the ImageMosaic plugin.  I can query them with standard WMS requests with the parameter TIME=yyyy-mm-dd.  The relevant data is quite sparse and I have created an SLD style which renders the background data as transparent.

What I would like is to pass a string such as `TIME=2013-01-01/2015-01-01` and have *all* of the images which fall within that time range returned and layered on top of one another.  What happens is that I get the latest image in that time range returned.  Is what I want to do possible with GeoServer, and if so how can I enable it?

**EDIT**: After further investigation it appears the GeoServer *is* layering the data, but:

- The background data value in the GeoTIFF is zero and NullValues in the Coverage Band details is set to zero, as is BackgroundValues
- Despite this, large regions of background data from the latest time are obscuring all the data from the earlier times
- The regions of no data, once layered and obscuring older data are then correctly rendered as transparent (as defined in the SLD style)
- I can't set the InputTransparentColor (or OutputTransparentColor), I think because the GeoTIFF is not RGB.  If I try, I get:

  `org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to create this mosaic
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported data type.`

So I think the problem is now that when using the ImageMosaic plugin, I cannot configure the value 0 to correspond to missing data properly.

I have tested all 16 combinations of:

- MergeBehaviour: FLAT or STACK
- BackgroundValues: 0 or empty
- Coverage Band Null Values: 0 or empty
- Coverage Band minRange: 0 or 1 (the values in the GeoTiff range from 0-4, with 0 representing no data)

None of these 16 combinations work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the structure of your raster data, so this might not be appropriate, but have you considered using a WCS instead of a WMS?  That would certainly allow you to query according to a time axis, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177305/wcs-time-dimension-always-returning-last-available-date for an example of such a query.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a configuration issue. Here is a sample that does apparently what you asked for, first link, only latest images (last month, configured to have "P1M/PRESENT" as the default time value):

http://cloudsdi.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/landsat8/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=landsat8%3AB3&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=768&BBOX=-125.52978515625%2C27.75146484375%2C-109.97314453125%2C44.62646484375

second link with range, all images in specified range:

http://cloudsdi.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/landsat8/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=landsat8%3AB3&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=768&BBOX=-125.52978515625%2C27.75146484375%2C-109.97314453125%2C44.62646484375&time=2016-09-01/2016-12-01

The layer in question is a image mosaic with time dimension enabled:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I tried this which led me to investigate further.  GeoServer is now layering the images, but the problem is that missing data is obscuring valid data - see the recent edit.