# Specify temporal domain subset in WCS/WPS

Tags: geoserver, wps, spatio-temporal-data, wcs

I am setting up the WPS module for GeoServer, which has worked well so far, except that all of our raster layers contain a temporal component to them, so I need to be able to specify the applicable date when I execute a WPS request. I can get the GeoServer WPS demo to give me a sample XML request, but it won't contain the temporal specification. All of my efforts to figure out how to specify this parameter have failed. How can I specify a date/time component in this WCS/WPS request?

POSTed URL: http://our-server.org/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=execute

Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" 
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
  xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" 
  xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" 
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
  xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 
    http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">  
  <ows:Identifier>ras:CropCoverage</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1"> 
             <ows:Identifier>my_layer</ows:Identifier>  
             <wcs:DomainSubset>
                <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4269">
                  <ows:LowerCorner>-125.020833333333 24.0625</ows:LowerCorner>
                  <ows:UpperCorner>-66.479166666662 49.937500000002</ows:UpperCorner>
                </ows:BoundingBox>
             </wcs:DomainSubset>
             <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>cropShape</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1">
          <![CDATA[{"type" : "MultiPolygon","coordinates" : [bunch of coordinates]  }]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for choosing WCS 1.1.1 over the newer versions supported by GeoServer?  If you are able to use version 2.0.1 then you should look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177305/wcs-time-dimension-always-returning-last-available-date

Comment: @nmtoken You're a godsend - that was it! I was doing everything right except the WCS spec! I don't know why Geoserver defaults to 1.1.1. You should put in an official answer so I can award you sweet, sweet rep.