# GetFeatureInfo with multiple TIME?

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo, wms-time

I have a GeoServer WMS with multiple layers, each with a time dimension (so its a WMS-T). I am able to query multiple layers simultaneously, but I am not able to query multiple TIME fields simultaneously. Is such a query possible, or would I have to make a script to query each TIME individually and then pool the results?

If this is possible with something other than Geoserver, or through some plugin, please let me know too.

This is the query I am trying to execute:

```
/geoserver/workspace/wms?SERVICE=WMS&\
VERSION=1.1.1&\
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&\
QUERY_LAYERS=workspace%3AACCGUST,workspace%3AT2M&\
LAYERS=workspace%3AACCGUST,workspace%3AT2M&\
INFO_FORMAT=application/json&\
FEATURE_COUNT=50&\
X=50&\
Y=50&\
SRS=EPSG%3A4326&\
WIDTH=101&\
HEIGHT=101&\
BBOX=-101.832275390625%2C31.42364501953125%2C-84.078369140625%2C49.17755126953125&\
TIME=2019-11-16T04:00:00.000Z,2019-11-17T04:00:00.000Z
```

And the output:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"Accum_Max_Gust":27.708324432373047}},{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"Temperature":33.7214469909668}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":2,"timeStamp":"2020-01-07T18:09:04.642Z","crs":null}
```

As far as I understand I can't use a WFS because I am querying a large NetCDF file and the data is too big (when extracted) to store in a database.

Comment: A WCS might be better

Comment: @nmtoken Can you please elaborate? It looks to me that WCS only returns images and other raster formats. https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wcs/outputformats.html

Comment: Generally, WCS services deal in multi-dimensional coverage data, xyzt for example, not just two dimensional raster images, but that might be a restriction of GeoServer.    https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177305/wcs-time-dimension-always-returning-last-available-date is related to you question and may be of interest

Comment: @nmtoken Still, WCS returns images. I need JSON.

Comment: WCS can return JSON, try rasdaman

Comment: Interesting... thanks. Can WCS return multiple time points with 1 request, though? Even the link you sent me to is only querying a single time point.

Comment: Yes, it can return everything, down to a single value in xyzt+ (any other dimensions you have) space.

Comment: Apologies for posting this as an answer - since SO's reputation system will not let me post this as a comment. I am chasing the same problem, and there are at least 3 threads on StackOverflow regarding this, which at best give hints towards solving this problem, like building a WCS in this one. Would you mind to share if you found a solution / How your solution looked like in practice / Perhaps provide a short outline / Or even link to a repository?

Comment: @J.B. I'm afraid I gave up on this approach. I ended up implementing something fully custom that reads my input data and parses out what I need (without geoserver).