# Working with time-rasters of a Geoserver's ImageMosaic

Tags: geoserver, wps, wcs, jiffle

I have stored a Sentinel2 14 bands raster with many dates on a ImageMosaic.

I use jiffle SLD styles for calculate on the fly different satelital indexes.

With that, I can select each date and generate any satelital index for watching.

Now, I need the NDVI average for each raster of the ImageMosaic

I think it could be done with WPS queries, using ras:jiffle for bands algebra and ras:CoverageClassStats (selecting one class) for calculate the mean of the result.

But this only could work with the last date of the ImageMosaic, because I can´t specify the entry layer date in the xml.

```
  <ows:Identifier>ras:CoverageClassStats</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>'workspace:layername'</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
```

How can I indicate the desired date of the raster?

I tried to add a wcs:DimensionSlice as recommended at [wcs Time Dimension Always Returning Last Available Date](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177305) but the request is always the same (with any date). This is my entire query:

```
  <ows:Identifier>ras:CoverageClassStats</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
            <ows:Identifier>{layer}</ows:Identifier>
              <wcs:DimensionSlice>
                <wcs:Dimension>time</wcs:Dimension>
                <wcs:SlicePoint>2020-08-14T00:00:00.000Z</wcs:SlicePoint>
              </wcs:DimensionSlice>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32721">
                  <ows:LowerCorner>594520.0 8623800.0</ows:LowerCorner>
                  <ows:UpperCorner>596140.0 8625810.0</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>stats</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>{stat}</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>band</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>0</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>classes</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>1</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>method</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>NATURAL_BREAKS</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>noData</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>noData</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
      <ows:Identifier>results</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

I have also tried nesting it inside `<wcs:DomainSubset>` but nothing changed.

EDIT:
GeoTools-Developer log:

````
Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = https://myserver/geoserver/
    identifier:
        value = ras:CoverageClassStats
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@5126618f (value: coverage, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@ca58fe (body: net.opengis.wcs11.impl.GetCoverageTypeImpl@e83dc91 (service: WCS, version: 2.0.1, baseUrl: null, extendedProperties: {}), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wcs, method: POST, mimeType: image/tiff, schema: null)input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@946857f (value: stats, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@6b0eb7c1input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@39d11ff6 (value: band, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@29263b09input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@14762e2f (value: classes, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@ad823dfinput[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@3bc7a3dd (value: method, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@232129dfinput[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@6837cc2 (value: noData, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@4d8e7116
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@4b51ea31 (value: results, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = application/json```

  [1]: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177305/wcs-time-dimension-always-returning-last-available-date
````

Comment: according to https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/wxs_ranges.html time is just another dimension so you select it in the same way as a bounding box.

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I posted an answer testing the inclusion of DimensionSlice, but I'm doing something wrong

Comment: turn logging up and try again

Comment: Are my attempts are with logging credentials enabled. I tried with postman and with python and same result: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Results><Class lowerBound="0.0" upperBound="1019.0" count="32562"><MEAN>516.1459676924018</MEAN></Class></Results>``` It works but don´t change with the time param

Comment: and what is in the log file?

Comment: Nothing. it seems that the parameter is simply ignored and the rest worked.

Comment: even when logging at GeoTools-Developer?

Comment: In GeoTools logs DimensionSlice don't exists...

Comment: Could not find declaration for: {http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1}DimensionSlice. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
2021-04-20 08:45:48,913 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1}DimensionSlice. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace